# PHP is showing errors with deprecated functions only some times

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-7, php-5.6, elfinder

I'm developing a web application that has a file manager. I'm using [elFinder](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder) . When i tested in a local xampp all went well, when I was upload the project to a demo server worked well too but now I'm working with the final server and i'm having big troubles with elFinder (file manager). I'm getting errors with deprecated functions, but in the past i runned the project in the same version (5.6.38 and 7.1) and I didn't get this problems. I have see that maybe is a problem with some configurations with php.ini, but i can't touch it. Do you know how I can solve this problem? Or do you know any alternative to elFinder that I can integrate with my app? I'm working with Codeigniter 3

Thanks all.

I paste the entire error

```
/mnt/web117/d2/53/59095953/htdocs/intranet/uploads/39/956
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
    <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
    <p>Severity: 8192</p>
    <p>Message: ini_set(): Use of iconv.internal_encoding is deprecated</p>
    <p>Filename: php/elFinder.class.php</p>
    <p>Line Number: 464</p>
    <p>Backtrace:</p>
    <p style="margin-left:10px"> File: /mnt/web117/d2/53/59095953/htdocs/intranet/application/vendor/studio-42/elfinder/php/elFinder.class.php<br /> Line: 464<br /> Function: ini_set </p>
    <p style="margin-left:10px"> File: /mnt/web117/d2/53/59095953/htdocs/intranet/application/controllers/Explorer_c.php<br /> Line: 104<br /> Function: __construct </p>
    <p style="margin-left:10px"> File: /mnt/web117/d2/53/59095953/htdocs/intranet/index.php<br /> Line: 315<br /> Function: require_once </p>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
    <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
    <p>Severity: 8192</p>
    <p>Message: ini_set(): Use of mbstring.internal_encoding is deprecated</p>
    <p>Filename: php/elFinder.class.php</p>
    <p>Line Number: 467</p>
    <p>Backtrace:</p>
    <p style="margin-left:10px"> File: /mnt/web117/d2/53/59095953/htdocs/intranet/application/vendor/studio-42/elfinder/php/elFinder.class.php<br /> Line: 467<br /> Function: ini_set </p>
    <p style="margin-left:10px"> File: /mnt/web117/d2/53/59095953/htdocs/intranet/application/controllers/Explorer_c.php<br /> Line: 104<br /> Function: __construct </p>
    <p style="margin-left:10px"> File: /mnt/web117/d2/53/59095953/htdocs/intranet/index.php<br /> Line: 315<br /> Function: require_once </p>
</div>{"cwd":{"isowner":false,"ts":1540638672,"mime":"directory","read":1,"write":1,"size":0,"hash":"l1_Lw","name":"Tasacion","rootRev":"","options":{"path":"","url":"","tmbUrl":"","disabled":["chmod"],"separator":"\/","copyOverwrite":1,"uploadOverwrite":1,"uploadMaxSize":2147483647,"uploadMaxConn":3,"uploadMime":{"firstOrder":"deny","allow":["image","text\/plain","application\/pdf"],"deny":["all"]},"dispInlineRegex":"^(?:(?:image|video|audio)|application\/(?:x-mpegURL|dash\\+xml)|(?:text\/plain|application\/pdf)$)","jpgQuality":100,"archivers":{"create":["application\/x-tar","application\/x-gzip","application\/x-bzip2","application\/x-xz","application\/zip"],"extract":["application\/x-tar","application\/x-gzip","application\/x-bzip2","application\/x-xz","application\/zip"],"createext":{"application\/x-tar":"tar","application\/x-gzip":"tgz","application\/x-bzip2":"tbz","application\/x-xz":"xz","application\/zip":"zip"}},"uiCmdMap":[],"syncChkAsTs":1,"syncMinMs":10000,"i18nFolderName":0,"tmbCrop":1,"substituteImg":true,"csscls":"elfinder-navbar-root-local"},"volumeid":"l1_","locked":1,"isroot":1,"phash":"","url":"#elf_l1_Lw","root":"l1_Lw"},"options":{"path":"Tasacion","url":"","tmbUrl":"","disabled":["chmod"],"separator":"\/","copyOverwrite":1,"uploadOverwrite":1,"uploadMaxSize":2147483647,"uploadMaxConn":3,"uploadMime":{"firstOrder":"deny","allow":["image","text\/plain","application\/pdf"],"deny":["all"]},"dispInlineRegex":"^(?:(?:image|video|audio)|application\/(?:x-mpegURL|dash\\+xml)|(?:text\/plain|application\/pdf)$)","jpgQuality":100,"archivers":{"create":["application\/x-tar","application\/x-gzip","application\/x-bzip2","application\/x-xz","application\/zip"],"extract":["application\/x-tar","application\/x-gzip","application\/x-bzip2","application\/x-xz","application\/zip"],"createext":{"application\/x-tar":"tar","application\/x-gzip":"tgz","application\/x-bzip2":"tbz","application\/x-xz":"xz","application\/zip":"zip"}},"uiCmdMap":[],"syncChkAsTs":1,"syncMinMs":10000,"i18nFolderName":0,"tmbCrop":1,"substituteImg":true},"files":[{"isowner":false,"ts":1540638672,"mime":"directory","read":1,"write":1,"size":0,"hash":"l1_Lw","name":"Tasacion","rootRev":"","options":{"path":"","url":"","tmbUrl":"","disabled":["chmod"],"separator":"\/","copyOverwrite":1,"uploadOverwrite":1,"uploadMaxSize":2147483647,"uploadMaxConn":3,"uploadMime":{"firstOrder":"deny","allow":["image","text\/plain","application\/pdf"],"deny":["all"]},"dispInlineRegex":"^(?:(?:image|video|audio)|application\/(?:x-mpegURL|dash\\+xml)|(?:text\/plain|application\/pdf)$)","jpgQuality":100,"archivers":{"create":["application\/x-tar","application\/x-gzip","application\/x-bzip2","application\/x-xz","application\/zip"],"extract":["application\/x-tar","application\/x-gzip","application\/x-bzip2","application\/x-xz","application\/zip"],"createext":{"application\/x-tar":"tar","application\/x-gzip":"tgz","application\/x-bzip2":"tbz","application\/x-xz":"xz","application\/zip":"zip"}},"uiCmdMap":[],"syncChkAsTs":1,"syncMinMs":10000,"i18nFolderName":0,"tmbCrop":1,"substituteImg":true,"csscls":"elfinder-navbar-root-local"},"volumeid":"l1_","locked":1,"isroot":1,"phash":"","url":"#elf_l1_Lw"}],"api":"2.1034","uplMaxSize":"32M","uplMaxFile":"20","netDrivers":["ziparchive"],"maxTargets":1000,"textMimes":["application\/x-empty","application\/javascript","application\/json","application\/xhtml+xml","audio\/x-mp3-playlist","application\/x-web-config","application\/docbook+xml","application\/x-php","application\/x-perl","application\/x-awk","application\/x-config","application\/x-csh","application\/xml","application\/sql"]}
```

Comment: Did you try running your application on docker or virtual machine?

Comment: The customer choose a php server I can't change it

Comment: Setting `iconv.internal_encoding` has been deprecated [since PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/iconv.configuration.php#ini.iconv.internal-encoding). I see you've already opened an [issue on Github](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/issues/2750), I'd recommend waiting to see what comes of that.

Comment: Yes I asked in github, but I ask here too because maybe is a problem with PHP conf and not with elFinder. The project is the same, so maybe is a PHP problem.